# Paypal Express Checkout Recurring, how to avoid ipn delay?

Tags: paypal

Im using Paypal Express checkout with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile INITAMT. I have set the start date of the recurring payment to the start of the second period and the INITAMT to the amount of a full first payment period. I get an instant confirmation that the profile has been created, my problem is however that the IPN with the payment confirmation can be delayed by up to 24h.. How do you usally solve this when you want to give your curstomer instant access to the subscription material? Just give them the access for free at first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPN should not be this delayed.  I have lots of Recurring Payments solutions configured for myself and my clients and I'm not seeing this issue anywhere.

If your IPN's are that delayed it could be that you're on a delayed que because of problems in the past with your IPN script.  Did you go through a period of time, by chance, where your had lots of IPN's failing for one reason or another?

Have you checked your IPN History in PayPal and your web server logs to ensure you're not getting errors when some IPN's hit your server?

PayPal's system sends the original IPN instantly (or very close to instant in most cases) and if your server returns anything other than 200 response they'll send it again...and again...and again...until it gets a good response.

If that happens a lot they will eventually place your IPN's on a delayed que so you don't keep chewing up their server resources, and if it keeps happening more they'll eventually kill your IPN altogether.

If that sort of thing was going on you should be getting email notifications about it, but that's the only thing I can think of that would cause you to have delayed IPN's, so I'd recommend checking your logs like I said as a first step to troubleshooting this.

Comment: I took a look at the IPN history and it was fine, my problem was that i assumed that i would get a separate IPN for the payment confirmation but now i noticed that it was confirmed in recurring_payment_profile_created under [initial_payment_status] => Completed

Comment: Ah, yes, that original IPN includes the transaction ID of that payment, too.

Comment: Limiting IPN because a development server didn't reply with 200OK is one of the most stupid move of Paypal I've heard. The purpose of testing IPN  - IS - to overcome all possible non Http 20x errors. If I never had any error in my API, then I'd be a god.

Comment: @LéonPelletier, that's what the sandbox is for.  Sounds like you're trying to test live IPNs from a live PayPal on a dev server..??  Use the sandbox to weed out all your potential errors and only go live when it's ready.  Then your live stuff would never be limited.

Comment: That's what I say, with a touch of vinegar. In a sandbox environment, I'm receiving IPN messages 20-30 minutes after the payment. So I understand that either I've been limited because of 500 errors, or IPN is food for dogs.